# Norm of operator $A$ st. $A^2 = I$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I'm wondering what can be said about the norm $||A||$ of an operator which squares to identity. All I can think of is that

$$1=||AA|| \leq ||A||^2$$

so that $||A|| \geq 1$. But can anything else be said? I'd really like it to be always equal to $1$ for a problem I'm working on, but can't seem to prove it.

The norm I'm considering is this:
$$||A|| = \sup_{x \in H} \frac{|Ax|}{|x|}$$

$H$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: Is that $|x| = \sqrt{|x_1|^2 + \cdots + |x_n|^2}$?

Comment: Edited to clarify. This is a part of a quantum mechanics problem so it's all about vectors in Hilbert space and hermitian operators

Comment: I'm not sure why I assumed this was about matrices... of course we could use the spectral theorem, but that's overkill.  I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A$ is symmetric (Hermitian), then that's true (assuming you're talking about the induced Euclidean norm). However, in general, $\|A\|$ can be very large. For example, take
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&t\\0&-1}
$$
with $t$ as large as you want to make it.

---

Note that for any operator on a Hilbert space, we have $\|A^*A\| = \|A\|^2$ (you should have this as a theorem somewhere).  Thus, we have
$$
\|A\|^2 = \|A^*A\| = \|A^2\| = \|I\| = 1
$$
so indeed, $\|A\| = 1$.

Comment: Yes, the ones I'm dealing with are hermitian. How to show the norm is one then? I edited the post to show which norm I'm talking about.

Comment: @DepeHb in fact, it is well known that for any Hermitian matrix $A$, $\|A\|$ is the largest absolute value of an eigenvalue of $A$.  That is, $\|A\|$ is also the "spectral radius" of $A$ when $A$ is Hermitian.

Comment: @DepeHb the key is to note that $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable, and that multiplying a matrix by a unitary matrix does not change its norm.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: Thanks, the key result that I was missing is $\|A^*A\| = \|A\|^2$

Answer (score 3):

It can be anything greater than $1$, take for instance
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&x\\1/x&0\end{bmatrix}
$$